How can I mock up a screen share?
I can use v4l2loopback to create a dummy video device, Xephyr to create a nested X server in its own window, and a gst pipeline to link the two so that the contents of the Xephyr window appear as my webcam.  This gives a nice sandbox where only the applications I want to share are made visible, and it means that I can switch back to the video conference without the other participants losing the view of the nested desktop.
However, this appears as my webcam, not as a screen share, and so I lose some desirable aspects of true screen sharing.  For instance, it means that each other user has to "pin" my feed in order that it doesn't lose focus when someone else speaks.  So I'm searching for a way to fool my browser into taking its screen share input from an X server other than the one in which it's running, or from a video device.
In case it matters, this is Firefox running in a Cinnamon environment.

On modern firefox (and if you have Wayland, necessarily always), screen sharing is done by firefox asking for a pipewire screen share list and streams, and then getting the data from there.
Pipewire itself goes through xdg-desktop-portal's interface for asking your screen manager for a capture backend. There's various implementation of these specific portals (for gtk, kde, wlroots,…) and they (most of them) implement the ScreenCast interface.
As far as I understand, there can only be one active implementation for each interface (like sound playback, displaying a file selection dialog, screen capture, video capture,…) of the selection of interfaces that xdg-desktop-portal's API offers. You can, however, select the one you'd like!
That way, you could run, say, your default generic gtk portal on your "main" X11, and a kde portal in your Xephyr, and start the KDE portal using that $DESKTOP.
Quite honestly, I'm not sure that's worth the effort, and I'm sure once you actually try you meet more obstacles. But in principle, as long as they have different DBUS names, you can have as many screencast-supporting portals as you'd like, and select the one you'd like your browser to use by starting it with a modified $XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment, which points it to a custom portals.conf.
